Console Application with params and display a guide
I'm creating a small console application with .NET8 that requires some parameters to run. I want to add an help if the parameters are empty. I read a Microsoft document where apparently it is easy to do it.
In the document, there is this example
/// <summary>
/// Converts an image file from one format to another.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The path to the image file to be converted.</param>
/// <param name="output">The name of the output from the conversion.</param>
/// <param name="xCropSize">The x dimension size to crop the picture.</param>
/// <param name="yCropSize">The x dimension size to crop the picture.</param>
public static void Main(FileInfo input, FileInfo output, 
    int xCropSize = 0, int yCropSize = 0)
{

}

They said that this generates an output like
imageconv:
  Converts an image file from one format to another.
Usage:
  imageconv [options]
Options:
  --input          The path to the image file that is to be converted.
  --output         The target name of the output after conversion.
  --x-crop-size    The X dimension size to crop the picture.
                   The default is 0 indicating no cropping is required.
  --y-crop-size    The Y dimension size to crop the picture.
                   The default is 0 indicating no cropping is required.
  --version        Display version information

Also, I can use this command
imageconv --input sunrise.CR2 --output sunrise.JPG

and automatically I get the parameters in the variables defines in the Main. But it doesn't work.
I tried to use
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

but this has always a value although there are no params and the value is the path of the application.
So, I don't get anything like that. Do you know if this implementation is still valid? How can I parse the parameters or show an help?

From msdn - "The first element is the executable file name".

Related.

JIC - have you installed System.CommandLine nuget?

@Enrico what packages did you actually use? What were the actual versions? .NET Core by itself can't parse arguments like this. The article you linked to refers to the System.Commandline package along with the experimental System.CommandLine.DragonFruit package that never reached Beta. What's your actual code and how did you actually call the program?

It doesn't work explains nothing. I've used both packages and they do work. Environment.GetCommandLineArgs is irrelevant. The actual documentation for DragonFruit is only found in the Github repo here

@PanagiotisKanavos at the moment I added just a static line to call my function. Because I wanted to give it to other colleagues, I was looking around how to read the parameters in a quick way. So, nothing is set in stone yet.

@Enrico don't describe your code. Post the actual code in the question. I'm creating a new tool using System.CommandLine right now. I've created dozens of CLI tools using it. It works. Help is printed automatically if you use -h or --help.  DragonFruit on the other hand is only meant for simple cases and as I already explained, is experimental. It does work in the simple cases. As soon as you want eg default values or multiple commands, DragonFruit becomes a hindrance, so I stopped using it

@Enrico did you get a NullReferenceException when you called the program without any parameters? That's because the FileInfo parameters were set to null

I copied the code from the Microsoft documentation. My code is mode simple, just string and a int

You need to install the System.CommandLine.DragonFruit package (enable preview packages if you are using UI) which will do the corresponding magic "turning" your custom Main method into the entrypoint one (as far as I can see it generates a real suitable entry point method which will use the Main you have defined):
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string input, string output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.DragonFruit" Version="0.4.0-alpha.22272.1" />
</ItemGroup>


See samples at their github repository - the one which directly references corresponding project

No repro with System.CommandLine.DragonFruit, as long as nulls are handled. The following code prints the help text if --help is passed to the command line.
namespace DragonFruitTest;

internal class Program
{
    

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an image file from one format to another.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The path to the image file to be converted.</param>
    /// <param name="output">The name of the output from the conversion.</param>
    /// <param name="xCropSize">The x dimension size to crop the picture.</param>
    /// <param name="yCropSize">The x dimension size to crop the picture.</param>
    public static void Main(FileInfo input, FileInfo output,
        int xCropSize = 0, int yCropSize = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"In: {input?.Name} - {input?.Exists}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Out: {output?.Name} - {output?.Exists}");
        Console.WriteLine($"XY: {yCropSize} - {yCropSize}");
    }
}

This prints
.\DragonFruitTest.exe --help
Description:
  Converts an image file from one format to another.

Usage:
  DragonFruitTest [options]

Options:
  --input <input>              The path to the image file to be converted.
  --output <output>            The name of the output from the conversion.
  --x-crop-size <x-crop-size>  The x dimension size to crop the picture. [default: 0]
  --y-crop-size <y-crop-size>  The x dimension size to crop the picture. [default: 0]
  --version                    Show version information
  -?, -h, --help               Show help and usage information

When the program is called without arguments, this appears:
.\DragonFruitTest.exe
In:  -
Out:  -
XY: 0 - 0

This works because the code explicitly handles nulls, by using input?.Name and input?.Exists. If the code used input.Name there would be a NullReferenceException.
With actual parameters :
.\DragonFruitTest.exe --input sunrise.CR2 --output sunrise.JPG
In: sunrise.CR2 - False
Out: sunrise.JPG - False
XY: 0 - 0

System.CommandLine.DragonFruit is experimental, never went beyond the Alpha stage and hasn't had a release since 2022. The actual documentation only exists in the Github Repo
It can only handle simple cases, so sooner or later, you'll find it's easier to use the System.CommandLine commands directly.
The project file only has a reference to DragonFruit. Notice that even though nullability is enabled, DragonFruit doesn't take it into account :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.DragonFruit" Version="0.4.0-alpha.22272.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


For a great real-world example, check how Aspire8 specifies its CLI commands and arguments. A separate Aspirate.Cli project specifies the root command. The actual commands are in another project and can be reused.
The Program.cs is just this. CommandLineBuilder, UseDefaults, Build, InvokeAsync are all parts of System.CommandLine :
AspirateCli.WelcomeMessage();

return await new CommandLineBuilder(new AspirateCli())
    .UseDefaults() 
    .Use... //Some custom middleware
    .Build()
    .InvokeAsync(args);

While the root command AspirateCli defines 9 other commands that can be used eg init, stop etc
internal class AspirateCli : RootCommand
{
    internal static void WelcomeMessage()
    {
        ...
    }

    public AspirateCli()
    {
        AddCommand(new InitCommand());
        AddCommand(new RunCommand());
        AddCommand(new StopCommand());
        AddCommand(new GenerateCommand());
        AddCommand(new BuildCommand());
        AddCommand(new ApplyCommand());
        AddCommand(new DestroyCommand());
        AddCommand(new SettingsCommand());
    }
}

You can't get such clean code with DragonFruit

You'd need to install
<PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.DragonFruit" Version="0.4.0-alpha.22272.1" />

In Visual Studio you need to go to package manager, check "Include prerelease" and look for System.CommandLine.DragonFruit - it will show you beta version of package 0.4.0-alpha.22272.1.
Then it works as intended:

